# SVN to git conversion: branch formation

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

My SVN repo looks like following:
     `branches/` `tags/` `trunk/`

Inside the branches folder, I have following:
`branches/dev1/example1` `branches/dev2/example2` `branches/dev3/example3`

I want to make `example1`,`example2` and `example3` as git branches during conversion.

```
git svn clone https://myurl -T trunk -b branches/dev1/example1 -b branches/dev2/example2 -b branches/dev3/example3 -t tags -A authors-transform.txt
```

I am getting into an infinite loop in linux. It is working fine (without forming the desired git branch though!) if I don't give the option of different branches and just give `-b branches`

Can anyone suggest a way to make the branches during the git conversion?

**Solution:**

```
 git svn clone https://myurl -T trunk -b branches/dev1 -b branches/dev2 -b branches/dev3 -t tags -A authors-transform.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close!

```
git svn clone https://myurl -T trunk -b branches -t tags -A authors-transform.txt
```

Option `-b` accepts a directory and treats every subdirectory there (`dev1`, `dev2` and `dev3` in your case) as a branch. You don't need to list all branches, just pass `-b branches`.

`-T trunk -b branches -t tags` could be abbreviated as `-s` or `--stdlayout`:

```
git svn clone https://myurl -s -A authors-transform.txt
```

Comment: what if the sub-dirs are actually `branches/user1/branchA` `branches/user1/branchB` `branches/user2/branchC` `branches/user22/branchQ`  ?  still only a single `-b` ?

Comment: No. `-b branches/user1 -b branches/user2` and so on. That is, you have to list all directories that contain branches.

Comment: Glad to be helpful!